# Append current month data to the master table containing previous period in SQL without creating 12 tables

Tags: sql

I have a 12 months data set which is very huge and if am trying to load all those at once in SQL, it is taking lot of time. Am looking for a better approach out of these 2 below:-

1. Should I create 13 tables to load 12 months of data in each table and 13th table to append from all the 12 tables
2. Create one table and append data to the master table every month (Don't know if this is possible)

Comment: the question why do you need all the rows, splitting one table will not remove the receiving of all rows, you can select month for month. if you really want to get all rows

Comment: I need all the rows to have Year to date view

Comment: "if am trying to load all those at once in SQL, it is taking lot of time"  So where's the data currently?

Comment: Which database you use? The SQL tag represents a **language**, but every database vendor has its own *dialect* and not all of them are *compatible*. As solution might depend on that, the question is: which database is it?

Comment: It is Onestream application which support SQL query